# Advice on next steps with our fledgling TeamCity / MSBuild setup

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity

we’ve now got a reasonable early days set up with TeamCity (6.5) & MSBuild.. So far only one solution is built this way until we get things working as we want before replicating, so..
Basically:

- One solution called by two builds – a CI Build on check-in to check
  the build isn’t broken, and a Test build which creates artifacts for
  testing.
- Assembly version numbers come from a single VersionInfo.cs
  file (is this a good idea?) that is a linked file in all projects in the solution. This
  method is detailed here :
  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328977/The-Right-Way-to-Version-Your-Assemblies
- The build step of both builds currently looks solely at the solution
  file, with MSBuild as the Build Runner

What I want to do next:

1. Version number to be Major.Minor.Release.Build Number. Therefore I need to set the last item to the TeamCity build number
2. In the test build only: artifacts to be copied to a separate location with a folder created with the name of the version number

So, finally to the question.. Do I need to

1. Create a separate build project with a pre-build step to amend the VersionInfo.cs AssemblyFileVersion to reflect the build number
2. in the new build project create a post build step for the copying of artifacts into a new directory in a separate directory?

Where I’m struggling with this is working out how the CI build will not pick these items up as both builds are using the same solution file, and whether I should be creating a new build file at all. If so do I leave the existing solution file as-is?

You can probably tell I'm a little confused ... Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to create yet another build configuration just to amend the version number.

TeamCity has a baked-in [AssemblyInfo Patcher](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/AssemblyInfo+Patcher) [build feature](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Adding+Build+Features) which can be used in your existing CI Build configuration. It will remove the need to do any assembly info versioning yourself as it applies the current build version (defined in TC for that build configuration) to all the AssemblyInfo.cs files located in the checkout directory before the build is executed. What you have done with the single shared VersionInfo.cs file isn't a bad thing, just unnecessary in this context (unless of course you are using it to share other AssemblyInfo information like company, tradmark, copyright etc).

A couple of options for storing your artifacts.

- You can retrieve build artifacts from the TeamCity [data directory](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/TeamCity+Data+Directory). The artifacts to copy to this directory are defined on the general settings page for each build configuration. See the [Build Artifact page](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Build+Artifact) for more info.
- Create a build step which runs a custom script (msbuild, nant, cmd line etc) to do the copying to your requirements.
- Another option which I tend to prefer is to push the artifacts back into source control where they can be checked out directly by other builds.

(all links are to TeamCity 6.5.x documentation)

You don't need two build configurations to achieve what you're doing; you can use one with multiple build steps. It doesn't really seem logical to break up the solution build and collection of artifacts into two separate configurations.

Comment: Thanks siyw. I'm not using the assemblyinfo patcher, but your advise gave me enough pointers to work through.

Comment: @Fetchezlavache glad to help. If you think your solution may help others you can always share it here too.

Comment: Will do siyw... once I've knocked a few other TC issues on the head :|